# How to extract data from a file using python and output to another file

Tags: python, information-extraction

I have a large file where I need to parse data repeatedly and output it to a new file. Here is an example of some of the content in the original file:

```
<example>
type        : FILE_CONTENT_CHECK
description : "This is a description"
info        : "Info!"
info        : ""
info        : "References:"
info            : "book1, book 2, etc"
file        : "blahblah.txt"
</example>
```

I need to be able to extract the description and all of the info lines after the :'s and place them in a new file. Keep in mind there are several instances of this in the same file and I'd like to be able to grab them all and export them to a new file.

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
if "description" in line: 
    for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: print l,
    print
if "info" in line:
for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: print l,
print
```

I've used this to be able to print the entire lines but would like something to output like the following:

```
"This is a description!"
"Info!"
""
"References:"
"book1, book 2, etc"
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: What does your expected output look like? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: Updated with expected output and some code I've cobbled together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a 'printme' flag.  If the flag is set, print the line's value and turn off the flag.  Flag will be set with 'description' or 'info' in key.

### source

```
EXAMPLE = '''
type        : FILE_CONTENT_CHECK
description : "This is a description"
info        : "Info!"
info        : ""
info        : "References:"
info            : "book1, book 2, etc"
file        : "blahblah.txt"
'''

do_print = False
for line in EXAMPLE.split('\n'):
    if ':' not in line:
        continue
    key,value = line.split(':',1)
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()

    if key in ('description', 'info'):
        print value
        do_print = True
        continue
    if do_print:
        print value
        do_print = False
```

### output

```
"This is a description"
"Info!"
""
"References:"
"book1, book 2, etc"
"blahblah.txt"
```